# tkinter doesnt work for me on anything

Tags: python, import, python3, pycharm

This is the code that I tried.

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.TK()

root.mainloop()

I tried using pycharm and sublime text. Pycharm wont show the blue letters on ".TK", "mainloop" and sublime text just wont let me code inside any of the files. Yes, I have python is my path and also i have python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3 you use:

from tkinter import*

window = Tk()

window.geometry("300x300")

window.title("welcome")

window.mainloop()

I should have been using this code....